# How to integrate Ionic UI with Android Java Code

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, apache-cordova

Good day,

I want to ask, how I can integrate the Ionic UI with Android Java Code?

Let's say, when I click the Ionic UI button, it should perform a logic coded using Java.

For example, my app is a calculator. Its UI is built using Ionic. I can input 2 numbers then when I click the button, it should calculate the sum of these 2 numbers using Java.

By the way, I'm using Android Studio for running my Ionic applications.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: how i would do this is to [create a Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/). This way, you will be able to trigger Java functions in your ionic Javascript code.

Comment: That is what android programming itself. In android all the UI is designed using xml and logical part are written by Java.

Comment: Can you give me a sample tutorial @Kaddath?

Comment: Sorry, i haven't created a cordova plugin recently and it's not fresh in my head, more, i never coded the communication functions between JS and Java myself. I just know the general theory. The link in the first comment is a good start